# Probability of there being at least one defective component with three independent events + 1 more event.

Tags: probability

The question is stated as follows.

"There are three separate independent components in a machine, each with a defection probability of [p = 0.001]. Further more there is another independent glitch in the system, which causes the failure of all these components simultaneously with a probability of [q = 0.00001].

What is the probability [P(A_{i})] of a specific component failing? What is the probability of the machine breaking ?"

My attempt at the solution:

The first part "seemed" trivial, but I am now unsure of it. If the probability of an individual component failing was p, then we simply add q to this to get the probability of a component failing i.e.

[P(B_{1}\cup B_{2} \cup B_{3} ) = P(B_{1}) + P(B_{1}) + P(B_{1}) - P(B_{1}\cap B_{2}) - P(B_{1}\cap B_{3}) - P(B_{2}\cap B_{3}) + P(B_{1}\cap B_{2}\cap B_{3})]

The second part is what stumps me. My first idea was that we need to find the probability of

[P(B_{1}\cap B_{2})]

But I can't seem to formulate any equations which are relevant. How do I take into account the union of all three sets? And how should I go about computing the above union. Any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Although adding p and q to get the probability of a given component breaking may seem intuitively the right thing to do, hopefully you can see that if you take $p=q=1/2$ (for instance), this method would tell you that each component breaks with certainty, which clearly isn't the case.

A nice way to approach this problem is to break everything down into events to do with the breakages: let $B_i$ be the event that component i (specifically) breaks, and let $C$ be the event where all components break simultaneously. The important thing to note, and maybe the question isn't particularly clear about, is that $B_i$ and $C$ are not disjoint (because they are independent), so it is possible to have a situation where component i specifically breaks, and all the component break simultaneously.

Now, the event that component i breaks somehow is given by $B_i \cup C$ - either it breaks specifically or everything breaks simultaneously. Can you find a way to express $\mathbb{P}(B_i \cup C)$ in terms of events you already know the probability of?